# Filter JSON data depending on selected jsTree node

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree, bootstrap-table

I have an example in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb1k2rw8/8/). I have a tree like this:

```
> Root > Parent[n] > Child[n].
```

In `Child` I have added an event handler. In the example it is in `Child1`, so if I click on `Child1` it will render a table with 3 rows from the variable `array`.

What I want is if I click on `Child1` it will filter the table (`array`) by branch "Parent1", this is, it will render the table with 2 rows *named* "Parent1". Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do two things to make your code work:

1. add jsTree css to make it expandable
2. you attached the `select_node` handler to something with id `$study` while it should have been `jstree`:

   ```
   $('#jstree').on('select_node.jstree', function (evt, data) {...})
   ```

Check update on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/Lb1k2rw8/7/).

You could simplify your code a little, if you care - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/Lb1k2rw8/6/).

**UPDATE**

If you want to filter the array by the parent text of selected node, you can replace this line: `$table.bootstrapTable('load', array);`

with:

```
var parentNodeId = $('#jstree').jstree().get_node(data.selected[i]).parent;    
var parentNodeText = $('#jstree').jstree().get_node(parentNodeId).text;

var filteredArray = array.filter(function(item){
   if (item.name === parentNodeText) {
       return item;
   }  
});

$table.bootstrapTable('load', filteredArray);
```

Comment: thanks for note, I fixed my example. This fiddle has been made just for example, but main question is still opening

Comment: So is it that you want to filter by `Child1` parent node caption?

Comment: absolutely right, if I clicked on Child1, it should filter to me Child1 Parent[n] caption

Comment: it looks right, but for some reason it doesn't work in fiddle... I've got your idea, your defined variables and set it up for items in array. I had this thought but couldn't understand how to define it in script

Comment: I found what the problem was. The names of your parent nodes in html markup have extra symbol in the end - the line break, so it was never equal to values in json. If removed, everything works. Check it out - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/5zgto3L5/

Comment: Thanks, glad I helped! I noticed that when logging both values to console.